# Expanding flex items to full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

I'm attempting to create a custom 'iTunes' style expanding layout. However, I am hitting a few issues. I had originally anticipated using flex-box for this. But I can't quite seem to do what I am looking to do.

I've attached an image of what I am trying to create. Essentially a grid of clickable thumbnails with expanding content which is full width. And the full width aspect is what I am struggling with. Am I going to have to set an explicit width on the expanding content or will it be possible for the content to flex to full width?

What I'm trying to create:

[image: What I'm trying to create]

I've attached a very basic codepen that demonstrates the issue I am having. If the first image was 'expanded' I would want it full width.

```css
.album-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.album {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.expanded-content {
  background: #212121;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="album-container">
  <album class='album'>
    <img alt="album-artwork" src="https://img.discogs.com/grVTPVqiRonKp5ly_ey-moBmO0c=/fit-in/600x600/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/R-11826116-1524151283-4015.jpeg.jpg">
    <div class="expanded-content">
      <div>Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not</div>
      <div>Arctic Monkeys</div>
    </div>
  </album>
    <album class='album'>
    <img alt="album-artwork" src="https://img.discogs.com/grVTPVqiRonKp5ly_ey-moBmO0c=/fit-in/600x600/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/R-11826116-1524151283-4015.jpeg.jpg">
  </album>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jakefauvel/pen/QoKdJP

Comment: Images of the rendered page aren't very useful to those who are trying to help you debug your code. Posting your relevant CSS and HTML will make your question more likely to receive a positive response and useful answers. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: Could you add your code so we can help you? In a nutshell I'd say that both Grid and Flexbox will work here, as for Flexbox you just should use it outside of main flexbox parent(where you have album covers as children), as for grid, you need to use `grid-column` style for this popover

Comment: @vicodin Thank you for your reply. I've attached a very basic codepen which hopefully demonstrates my issue. I've tried setting width: calc(100vw - myMargin) which works for the expanding content on the first item. But the second will obviously overflow the page. Which also seems hacky.

Comment: You're welcome? Thanks for improving your question. I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep exactly this HTML structure, and have only one popover at a time, This approach could help you(see snippet)

But I think it would be better and cleaner to restructure HTML code, for example, move your `.expanded-content` out from `.album-container` and change it's content with JavaScript if possible.

```css
.album-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.album {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.expanded-content {
  background: #212121;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="album-container">
  <album class='album'>
    <img alt="album-artwork" src="https://img.discogs.com/grVTPVqiRonKp5ly_ey-moBmO0c=/fit-in/600x600/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/R-11826116-1524151283-4015.jpeg.jpg">
    
  </album>
    <album class='album'>
    <img alt="album-artwork" src="https://img.discogs.com/grVTPVqiRonKp5ly_ey-moBmO0c=/fit-in/600x600/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/R-11826116-1524151283-4015.jpeg.jpg">
<div class="expanded-content">
      <div>Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not</div>
      <div>Arctic Monkeys</div>
    </div>
  </album>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, cheers! Quite embarrassed at how simple the solution was. The code pen was a basic example, it will actually be a Vue component so all of this data will be dynamic. I'll be looping and mounting 'albums' based on the data coming from the backend. The main reason I had the expanding content as part of an album was it relates directly to that particular album, was trying to keep it all fairly self contained to an individual album.

Comment: Well, than this solution should work for you :) You're welcome

Comment: I've taken another look at this this evening. The position absolute works great for getting that full width expanding content, however, I've noticed now that the album-container is now not accounting for the expanded contents height. Is this something I'm going to have to solve using JS and setting the height of the parent, or is there a CSS fix to make the parent still account for the child's height?

Comment: I'm right in thinking the absolute positioning is removing it from the document flow?

Comment: yep it removes. You can add bottom-padding with the value of expanded-content height